# High Loss despite correct Weight and bias -Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am a begginer user of tensorflow and am making a program to explain linear regression. I have one input which is the year the house was bought (my program is a house price identifier) and the weight and bias were identical to excel's trendline linear equation. Unfortunately the cost ended at 70.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = dir_path+ "\ActualHousePriceData7.csv"

learn_rate=0.001


w=tf.Variable(([1.00]),tf.float32)
b=tf.Variable(([1.00]),tf.float32)
x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


init= tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


all_x1s = []
all_ys = []

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with open(filename) as inf:
        # Skip header
        next(inf)
        for line in inf:
            # Read data, using python, into our features
            housenumber, _x1, _y_= line.strip().split(",")
            all_x1s.append(float(_x1))
            all_ys.append(float(_y_))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
y_pred = (x*w)+ b
squared_deltas = tf.square(y_ - y_pred)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)

print (all_x1s)
for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:all_x1s ,y_:all_ys})
    print("After %d iteration:" % i)
    print("W: %f" % sess.run(w))
    print("b: %f" % sess.run(b))
    print("Cost")
    print(sess.run(cost,feed_dict={x:all_x1s, y_:all_ys}))
```

Is there a problem with how I am outputting the cost or is it something else? Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `squared_loss`, its recommended to use mean of the loss not sum.

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(squared_deltas)
```